# Протокол IP

Tags: ip

Как определить какая маска например у ip=192.168.17.28 ?
как это делают?или маска подсети задается вместе с ip?

Comment: а почему например не 255.255.255.254?
как узнать какая маска сети?

Comment: Спасибо , наконец понял)!!!

Comment: только откуда берется маска??
как создается?

Comment: Не сочти за саморекламу, но заново же не писать - http://hashcode.ru/questions/241252#241269

Comment: @hil400k, ну, вообще-то существует  такое понятие, как класс сети и соответствующая ему маска по умолчанию.

Почитайте [IP Default Subnet Masks For Address Classes A, B and C](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPDefaultSubnetMasksForAddressClassesABandC.htm)

Comment: @eicto, речь ведь об ipv4.

Comment: @eicto, Вы хотите сказать, что зная IPv4 нельзя достоверно определить маску сети? Да, нельзя.

Можно лишь сделать предположение, основываясь на классе IP адреса.

Comment: @avp понятие "класс сети" уже давно устарело и имеет только историческое значение, если не согласны подскажите пожалуйста какого класса сеть ipv6

2001:1c0:1000:d::/48

@avp оно и в ipv4 устарело, причем давно, эти классы вводились не чтобы маски стандартные делать :) http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Классовая_адресация более того - понятие маски противопоставляется понятию классов, просто когда переходили, чтобы админы с ума не сошли, им выдали вот такое соответствие что C-24, B - 16 , A -8 .

-----

я хочу сказать , что понятие "класс сети" исчезло из сетевых стандартов в первой половине 90х

Answer (score 1):

Маска ip адреса всегда полная (32 поднятых бита). маска отличная от /32 указывает на сеть а не на ip. При инициализации интерфейса, маска нужна, чтобы указать в какой сети искать соседей (в домосетях обычно единственный доступный сосед - шлюз) так вот. В случае не p2p соединений (pppd и потомки обычно) шлюз должен находится в одной сети с хостом. например

запись 192.168.2.34/24 означает, что адрес сети 192.168.2.0 и соседние хосты (доступ к которым может быть без роутера) могут находиться в диапазоне от 192.168.2.1 до 192.168.2.254 (0 - адрес сети, 255- broadcast)

Смысл стоит понимать так - это не по ip адресу вычисляется маска, а по маске определяются параметры сети. Маску и адрес должен передать хост, который выдал адрес, либо, при установке вручную, её сообщает администратор сети.

Маску  выдумывает админ. в соответствии с планом развития сети и состояния тактической ситуации в сети. иногда(всё чаще) это делается (полу)автоматически

---

касаемо классов сетей, я хотел бы всё таки закрыть этот вопрос:

Классов сетей (class A/class B/class C) и в общем-то никогда не существовало в виде масок /8 /16 и /24, до того как ввели бесклассовые сети публиковались примерно такие документы [rfc990](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc990)

которые весьма подробно описывали классы сетей, но потом (1992) вышел [rfc1338](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1338) описывающий проблемы классовой организации (ограниченность Class B, переполнение таблиц маршрутизации и прочее) предлагающий решение этих проблем, по всей видимости окончательно новый план был принят в rfc1519

С тех пор в общем много битиков утекло.

Для примера можно почитать [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), обратите внимание на прошедшее время.

Теперь о том, почему я лично считаю упоминание классов не только не полезным но и вредным,

Давая понятие "класс сети" вы только запутываете человека рассказывая ему старые легенды, кроме того, человек долго не  может выйти за подразумеваемые этим понятием "стандартные маски" сетей /8 /16 /24, которые ничего общего с классовой организацией не имеют, вместо того чтобы сказать что маска сети это просто битовая маска, они начинают думать о каких-то волшебных цифрах и стопорятся когда пытаются понять /28 /30 /14 или не могут понять почему маски 255.255.255.250 не существует.